# How come my calculated engine torque is so much less than the manufacturer's specifications?

Tags: automotive-engineering, torque, car, acceleration

Here are my calculations. Am I doing anything wrong?[image]

Comment: Your ecu might be limiting the torque in first gear. Try again in second gear.

Comment: What about torque produced by the engine? Some cars are available with different engines which develop more or less power.

Comment: You ignored the torque required to accelerate the rotating parts of the engine and transmission, and the wheels of the car. (That includes everything, not just the engine flywheel - crankshaft, camshaft, water pump, transmission drive shafts, etc...)

Comment: alephzero, yup you're right. If I try this in a higher gear at a higher speed then the effect of these factors will be reduced. Right?

Comment: Phil Sweet, will do. Thx for the tip